# error en CameraPosition en ionic 3

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, google-maps, ionic3

estoy realizando unas pruebas con googlemaps usando ionic 3.14

He logrado visualizar el mapa, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora estoy intentando realizar la geocalizacion para que muestre mi locación actual usando el método CameraPosition
Este es el código que he podido encontrar

```
moveCamera(loc: LatLng){
 // create CameraPosition

let options: CameraPosition = {
  target: loc,
  zoom: 18,
  tilt: 30
};

this.map.moveCamera(options)
```

}

Pero tengo un error en CameraPosition

```
ts] Generic type 'CameraPosition<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

import CameraPosition

¿cual es el error? , Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es la siguiente, definir el tipo que en este caso es `LatLng` :

```
   moveCamera(loc: LatLng){
   // create CameraPosition
   let camaraPosition: CameraPosition<LatLng> = {
    target: loc,
    zoom: 18,
    tilt: 30
  };

  this.map.moveCamera(camaraPosition)
}
```